# Push link inside html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a div tag

```
<div id="img"> <div>
```

and a script in page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function img(){
   document.getElementById('img').innerHTML="<a href="/lime/link.html"><img src="/lime/img.png"></a>";}
</script>
```

how to put the image on the div with link on pageload?

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.onload` for that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
      document.getElementById('img').innerHTML='<a href="/lime/link.html"><img src="/lime/img.png"></a>';
    };
</script>
```

**Note:** You were having quotes mis-match problem, I have fixed that too :)

Answer (score 0):

You have `"` characters inside a `"`-string.
Therefore, the string ends at the first `"`, and the rest of the line becomes a syntax error.

You should use `'` instead of `"` to create the string, like this:

```
'<a href="/lime/link.html"><img src="/lime/img.png"></a>'
```

Also, the code can only work if the `img` element has already been parsed.
If the `<script>` block appears before the `<div>` tag, you'll need to execute the code in the `onload` event.

Finally, your example defines a function, but never calls the function.

To execute the code, you need to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onload`-event

```
function appendHref() {
    document.getElementById('img').innerHTML="<a href=\"/lime/link.html\"><img src=\"/lime/img.png\"></a>";
}

if (window.addEventListener){      
    window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {appendHref();}, false);} 
else if (window.attachEvent){     
    window.attachEvent('onload', function(e) {appendHref();}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `window.onload=img;` to your script, outside of the function img (){}